# What Warframe quests are there?

Tags: warframe

So, the Quests page on the Codex screen has 4 boxes.  The first two are Vor's Prize, which is the tutorial quest, and Howl of the Kubrow, which is the second quest.

Now I know there's a third quest, and that's for Mirage, the newest warframe, but since there are 4 boxes, does this mean there's a 4th secret mission?

What quests are available to me, and how do I start them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There are **17** Warframe quests so far.

The [list of quests](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Quest):

- Vor's Prize
- Once Awake
- Stolen Dreams
- Howl of the Kubrow
- The Archwing
- The Limbo Theorem
- Hidden Messages
- Natah
- A Man of Few Words
- Patient Zero
- The New Strange
- The Second Dream
- Sands of Inaros
- The Jordas Precept
- The War Within
- The Glast Gambit
- The Silver Grove

Answer (score 1):

1. Vor's Prize (tutorial quest)
2. Howl of the Kubrow (Get your own fur ball quest)
3. Hidden Messages (Mirage Quest)
4. Unavailable Broken/Bugged quest (source devstream 33 below)